# Postgres CUBE search - optional/any value

Tags: sql, postgresql, cube

I am using Postgres CUBE to search for the best matches of an array with 4 values. It looks like this:

```
SELECT macros <-> CUBE (ARRAY [1, 19, 18, 342]) AS distance
```

I would like to have an option to make some of the values nullable/any value, but I can't seem to find any solutions for this. Can anyone help me out here? This is what I would like to do:

```
SELECT macros <-> CUBE (ARRAY [NULL, NULL, NULL 342]) AS distance
```

But this results in *"Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  cannot work with arrays containing NULLs"*.

How can I do this, only searching for the last value of the array, without losing the CUBEs performance? It searches through +10 million records.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. The key was to use CUBE_SUBSET() - like so:

```
CUBE_SUBSET (macros, ARRAY[4]) <-> CUBE (ARRAY [342]) AS distance
```